# How to access protected variable in Zend forms?

Tags: php, oop, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

i am trying to create a dynamic multioption select using dynamic values for a shipping cost pulldown,

the array comes in and creates the select input fine but the protected values are omitted. this makes no sense to me.  i even tried using a public getter to access the protected value but it still comes in blank.

```
        protected $_regular     = 4.95;
        protected $_oneDay      = 14.95;
        protected $_twoDay      = 14.95;

        public function getShippingOpts(){

            return array(
                "regular"=>"Regular 5-7 Business Days $".$this->_regular,
                "two-day"=>"Express 3-4 Business Days $".$this->_twoDay,
                "one-day"=>"Overnight 1-2 Business Days $".$this->_oneDay
            );
        }
```

here is the $form code placed within the form's init function:

```
    $shType = new Zend_Form_Element_Radio("sh_type");
    $shType->setLabel("Please select a type of shipping")
            ->setAttrib('class', 'co-shipping-type')
            ->setRequired(true)
    ->setMultiOptions(ORed_Shipping_LabelFactory::getShippingOpts());
    $shTypeToSubmit = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden('speed');
    $shipping2->addElements(array($shType, $shTypeToSubmit));
```

Comment: The code as posted, appears correct. Can you post the code which initializes the $form object?

Comment: Maybe the problem is, that you are trying to call `getShippingOpts()` like a static method? Try adding the static keyword the the function and the properties (and fix `$this->_regular` to `self::$_regular`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are not creating instance of ORed_Shipping_LabelFactory hence you cannot use instance variables (variables which starts with $this are instance variables) .

```
   static $_regular     = 4.95;
            static $_oneDay      = 14.95;
            static $_twoDay      = 14.95;

            public static function getShippingOpts(){

                return array(
                    "regular"=>"Regular 5-7 Business Days $".self::$_regular,
                    "two-day"=>"Express 3-4 Business Days $". self::$_twoDay,
                    "one-day"=>"Overnight 1-2 Business Days $". self::$_oneDay
                );
            }
```

Comment: thanks so much, makes complete sense now, my ideal scenario is for those vars to get set from the db so looks like i need an instance after all.